# StringMatchQ fails using Alternatives with complex pattern

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

Alternatives seems to work fine with these simple patterns

```
StringMatchQ["Eric", Alternatives["Eric", "Geoff"]]    
(* True *)

StringMatchQ["Eric", Alternatives["Geoff", "Eric"]]
(* True *)
```

I have a more complex pattern that matches strings enclosed with parenthesis and optionally the string "sh" at the end. The patterns are below where I assign them to a variable

```
patternText = 
 StartOfString ~~ "(" ~~ 
  textContent : ((Join[{WordCharacter}, {"-", "+", "\\", ".", ",", 
        "/", ":", " "}] ..)) ~~ ")" ~~ EndOfString

patternTextShow = 
 StartOfString ~~ "(" ~~ 
  textContent : (Join[{WordCharacter}, {"-", "+", "\\", ".", ",", "/",
        ":", " "}] ..) ~~ ")sh" ~~ EndOfString
```

The patterns work fine by themselves

```
StringMatchQ["(Eric)", patternText]
(* True *)

StringMatchQ["(Eric)", patternTextShow]
    (* False *)

StringMatchQ["(Eric)sh", patternText]
(* False *)

StringMatchQ["(Eric)sh", patternTextShow]
(* True *)
```

The results are as expected.

When I use `Alternatives`, however, it only works if the matching pattern is first, fails otherwise.

```
StringMatchQ["(Eric)", Alternatives[patternTextShow, patternText]]
(* False *)

StringMatchQ["(Eric)", Alternatives[patternText, patternTextShow]]
(* True *)

StringMatchQ["(Eric)sh", Alternatives[patternTextShow, patternText]]
(* True *)

StringMatchQ["(Eric)sh", Alternatives[patternText, patternTextShow]]
(* False *)
```

Why is this?

I found that using `Or` solved the problem but would like to understand why the `Alternatives` approach fails.

```
Or[
 StringMatchQ["(Eric)", patternTextShow],
 StringMatchQ["(Eric)", patternText]
 ]
(* True *)

Or[
 StringMatchQ["(Eric)", patternText],
 StringMatchQ["(Eric)", patternTextShow]
 ]
(* True *)

Or[
 StringMatchQ["(Eric)sh", patternTextShow],
 StringMatchQ["(Eric)sh", patternText]
 ]
(* True *)

Or[
 StringMatchQ["(Eric)sh", patternText],
 StringMatchQ["(Eric)sh", patternTextShow]
 ]

(* True *)
```

Comment: I would love to. There used to be an In Out merge in the Markup menu but I no longer see it. Can you refresh my memory as to how to do it? Meanwhile I will manually edit.

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t know of an automated way here in the editor. Normally when I copy code from MMA by selecting it and CTRL+C, the In and Out don’t come with it. In fact I was wondering how you had gotten them in the first place :-) Thank you for editing them out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem arises from naming the inner sub-patterns in your two pattern definitions with the same identifier. When you combine the patterns with `Alternatives`, you then have a pattern with two sub-patterns tagged with the same name, which is bad.

Consider this simpler case.

```
pattern1 = StartOfString ~~ "(" ~~ t : WordCharacter .. ~~ ")1" ~~ EndOfString;
pattern2 = StartOfString ~~ "(" ~~ t : WordCharacter .. ~~ ")2" ~~ EndOfString;
StringMatchQ["(Eric)1", pattern1 | pattern2]
StringMatchQ["(Eric)1", pattern2 | pattern1]
StringMatchQ["(Eric)2", pattern1 | pattern2]
StringMatchQ["(Eric)2", pattern2 | pattern1]
```

> True
> False
> False
> True

It is corrected by giving the tagged sub-patterns different names.

```
pattern1 = StartOfString ~~ "(" ~~ s : WordCharacter .. ~~ ")1" ~~ EndOfString;
pattern2 = StartOfString ~~ "(" ~~ t : WordCharacter .. ~~ ")2" ~~ EndOfString;
StringMatchQ["(Eric)1", pattern1 | pattern2]
StringMatchQ["(Eric)1", pattern2 | pattern1]
StringMatchQ["(Eric)2", pattern1 | pattern2]
StringMatchQ["(Eric)2", pattern2 | pattern1]
```

> True
> True
> True
> True

Comment: You nailed it. Thank you. When I named the patterns and used the variable names it obscured the fact that the identifier names were identical.